# wav data как переписать

Tags: c++

есть спек : [тыц](http://audiocoding.ru/article/2008/05/22/wav-file-structure.html), надо переписать вав файл из 16 в 8 бит.
переписываю хедер :

```
oheader.byteRate = header.byteRate / 2;
oheader.subchunk2Size = header.subchunk2Size / 2;
oheader.blockAlign = header.blockAlign / 2;
oheader.chunkSize = 36 + oheader.subchunk2Size;
int numSamples = oheader.chunkSize/2;
```

data выглядит следующим образом: * бит левый канал/ * бит правый канал и так далее.
собственно как переписать data. язык c++

Comment: @Abyx я не прошу написать за меня код, спасибо что обратили внимание на данный вопрос, просто в спеке нету как перезаписать data. желаю вам тоже сходить на freelance.com

Comment: Когда не помогает спека, возьмите обычный редактор аудио и проделайте нужную операцию в нём. Потом посмотрите содержимое файлов, которые редактор произвёл. Сравните с тем, что получается у вас, и исправьте ошибку.

Comment: @Discord именно необходимо мне узнать как переписывать data, как она выглядит я прочитал в теории. но я нигде не видел как она редактируется на практике.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить из 16 бит 8 старших (с изменением типа с условного short в условный signed char), в простейшем случае нужно выбросить младшие 8 бит.

```
short  x = ...;
signed char y = (signed char) ( x / 256 )
```

P.S.

> ```
> oheader.subchunk2Size = header.subchunk2Size / 2;
> ...
> oheader.chunkSize = 36 + oheader.subchunk2Size;
> int numSamples = oheader.chunkSize / 2;
> ```

Ты уверен что при уменьшении разрядности уменьшится количество семплов? Это выглядит очень подозрительно. И вот это вот загадочное 36, тоже.

Comment: Форматируйте код с помощью отступов в 4 пробела, также мы можете выделить отрывок кода в сообщении и нажать сочетание Ctrl+K, чтобы добавить или удалить отступ.